# how does django class based views know which context means what

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Let's say I have a model of blog:

```
#models.py
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And in views I have a class based view:

```
#views.py
class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Blog
```

And I refer that view as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
```

Now django DetailView accepts the context variable name to be 'object'. So in the html, I do something like:

```
<<! blog_detail.html -->
<p>{{ object.content }}</p>
```

Now, if I go to like localhost:8000/post/1 ; that renders contents which I manually created using manage.py shell and those are specific contents of specific blogs.

Now, my question is, how does django know that 'object' explicitly means 'a' discrete blog?
Like here I am only referring that primary key in url. So is it like django grabs that primary key from url and then passes that primary key as context and then when I refer 'object.content' then django grabs the object that has primary key as 1 from the model Blog and then displays the actual content? Is it like it or something else? I really can't understand. Any help with a detailed explanation about how it happens will be really be helpful.

Comment: The logic for that in implemented in `DetailView` and its base classes.

Comment: Can you please give a reference or elaborate a bit as that would be really helpful

Comment: The [code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/views/generic) and the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/). Happy reading!

Comment: [This site](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/) is a good overview on how the various generic class-based views work. Note if you set the class attribute `context_object_name` to `post` in your `BlogDetailView`, you'd be able to refer to the `object` as `post` (e.g. `{{ post.content }}`) which helps readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, my question is, how does django know that 'object' explicitly means 'a' discrete blog? Like here I am only referring that primary key in url. So is it like django grabs that primary key from url

Yes.

> and then passes that primary key as context and then when I refer 'object.content' then django grabs the object

Nope. The urlresolver extracts the pk value from the url and pass it to `DetailView.get()`. Then `DetailView.get()` retrieves the matching model instance and passes it to the template, under the name "object".

Now has Klaus D. mentions, Django is OSS, so you can just read the code to find out how womething really works (if the - rather extensive - doc doesn't already answer your question) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the flow of control for a DetailView in the Django documentation about [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview).
If you take a look at the declaration of your View, you have already specified the Model on which the query is to be created.
From the linked documentation, the `get_object` method would fetch the object with `id/pk` specified in your URL.

The object is then added into context via the `get_context_data` method. The `.content` method/property is also defined in one of the base classes of the `model object` which gives you the HTML representation for the attributes defined on the `object` which you see in the template.

Hope this gives an explanation about the flow. However, you should be reading the documentation and using debuggers to understand the flow of the views rather than asking such questions here. :)

The comment by @dirkgroten also links to a very good site related to Django's views and methods. [ccbv.co.uk](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/)